# What Statistics Can I Get from This Grading Procedure

Tags: probability, data-mining, scoring-rules

I am a mathematician, not a statistician.  So, I am hoping this question is not too broad.  I'll delete if the community wishes.

I recently read on [Terence Tao's blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2016/06/01/how-to-assign-partial-credit-on-an-exam-of-true-false-questions/) about a way to give partial credit for multiple choice tests that allows you to assess a students ability and removes incentive to guess.  For those not wanting to read:  If you have an exam with four multiple choice options, you let your students assign probabilities to each option indicating how certain they are the option is correct.  If you assign choice $x$ probability $p(x)$, and $x$ is correct, you get $1 + \log_4(p(x))$ points.  We treat $p(x) = 0$ as $p(x) = 0.001$ so as not to break the system.

Given this setup, what sorts of useful data can I extract?  For example, a flatter distribution for a given question will indicate that students thought that question was hard.  Are there standard statistical methods for this kind of data analysis?

Comment: The link deals with true or false questions only.  So it only gives tow choices. The Educational Testing Service (ETS) does penalize students for guessing on multiple choice questions on the SAT and GRE exams.

Comment: @MichaelChernick In Terry's blog, he uses $\log_2$ instead of $\log_4$.  All his analysis carries over to $n$ choices by using $\log_n$.  Penalizing students for guessing is not the only good feature.  Most importantly, Terry's method gives us a level of certainty.  That's the feature that interests me most.

Comment: From a practical psychometric perspective, I don't this is a good method for an ordinary classroom test. People are notoriously bad at reasoning about probability. Students' performance will depend a lot on their statistical savvy as opposed to the knowledge you're trying to test.